# Adding column to database table in rails 1.2.6(legacy version)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 1.2.6. (Its old I know. But I have to use it.) I need to add column to users table. I cant use rails generate migration with rails 1.2.6. I need to add a versioned db migrate file. How can I do that? 
I want to add product column to users table. I created a file in the db/migrate folder with following contents.

```
class AddProductToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
      add_column :users, :product, :string
    end
    def self.down
      remove_column :users, :product
    end
end
```

I used `script/generate migration AddProductToUser`. It gives an error as 
`undefined method 'cache' for Gem:Module`.

Any pointers on how to run migration in rails 1.2.6(<2.x) will also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your migrate file looks (almost) fine, does the filename match the class name, and does it have a sequence number at the beginning that follows on from the previous migrate?

Slight change:

```
# db/migrate/123_add_product_to_user.rb
class AddProductToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :product, :string
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :product # note sure where radius came from?
  end
end
```

Then should just be run with `rake migrate`

[More info at apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/v1.0.0/ActiveRecord/Migration)

Comment: I am getting an error as below.  After using `rake migrate`.  `rake aborted!  NoMethodError: undefined method 'cache' for Gem:Module
`.  File name is correct with version `142_add_product_to_user.rb`